# Label on pie chart slice using textPath not displaying

Tags: svg, amcharts

I'm writing an Amcharts plugin that puts a pie chart slice label on the slice's path. I do this by adding IDs to the slice `<path>`, moving the `<text>` in the label inside a `<textPath>` that references that `<path>`. The output looks correct but the text is not visible. It doesn't seem to be a browserism because several SVG validators do the same thing. Any idea why the `<textPath>` isn't being displayed?

I manipulate the chart data like so:

```
var chart = event.chart;
var div = chart.div;
var divId = div.id;
var chartData = chart.chartData;

chart.container.container.setAttribute("xmlns","http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");
chart.container.container.setAttribute("xmlns:xlink","http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");

    for(var i = 0; i < chartData.length; i++) {
        if(chartData[i].dataContext.wrapLabel) {
            /**
             *  Create an ID for the <path> that the label will wrap onto
             */
            chartData[i].wedge.node.firstChild.setAttribute("id",divId + "-" + i);
            // create the textPath element and set its href to the id we added to the path
            var n = document.createElement('textPath');
            n.setAttribute("xlink:href","#" + divId + "-" + i);
            // Now move all of the tspan nodes underneath the textPath node
            while(chartData[i].label.node.hasChildNodes()) {
                n.appendChild(chartData[i].label.node.firstChild);
            }
            // and then append the textPath node to the <text> node
            chartData[i].label.node.appendChild(n);
        }
    }
```

This produces the following SVG:

```
<svg version="1.1" style="position: absolute; width: 1000px; height: 1000px; top: -0.457382px; left: -0.002841px;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<g opacity="1" aria-label=": 24.38% 84 " visibility="visible" transform="translate(0,0)">
  <path cs="1000,1000" d=" M450.03754782613004,498.06263767618003 L375.0938695653251,495.1565941904501 A125,125,0,0,1,499.99999999999994,375 L500,450 A50,50,0,0,0,450.03754782613004,498.06263767618003 Z" fill="#741010" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2" stroke-opacity="1" fill-opacity="1" id="chart2-0"></path>
</g>
<g visibility="visible" transform="translate(0,0)" opacity="1">
   <text y="5" fill="#fff" font-family="Verdana" font-size="9px" opacity="1" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(552,554)" style="cursor: default;" visibility="visible">
      <textpath xlink:href="#chart2-0">
          <tspan y="5" x="0">$260.5B</tspan>
          <tspan y="16" x="0">Satellite</tspan>
          <tspan y="27" x="0">Industry</tspan>
      </textpath>
   </text>
</g>
</svg>
```

(Edited down for brevity.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd be wanting

```
n.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "xlink:href","#" + divId + "-" + i);
```

because you can only set attributes in the null namespace with setAttribute.

Nor can you set a namespace with setAttribute so I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with

```
chart.container.container.setAttribute("xmlns","http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");
chart.container.container.setAttribute("xmlns:xlink","http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");
```

The fact that the textPath element is entirely lower case in the output suggests that something has gone wrong in its creation. Either you incorrectly wrote it in lower case or you've created it (and possibly all your other elements) in the wrong namespace.

See [the MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course) for more details about namespaces.